# How to disable USB MTP-connection (Honeycomb)

Tags: android

I'm using Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1. After connecting it to PC, I always get message "USB MTP-connection", when I connect it to AC to fill the battery.

I can only charge the battery if tablet is tuned off.

Any good solution how to turn this USB MTP connection off so I could normally charge battery.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with programming Ask this question in Android Enthusiasts: http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also the device should charge while MTP is connected.

Comment: I think that also. But unFortunately it is not. Only when it is turned off.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general Android usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the home screen, go to Menu > Settings > Applications and then enable USB Debugging. This should enable you to charge the tablet like normal.

Comment: Tried this several times, but still not working. Always detect "MTP-connection" also if I connect table only on AC.

Comment: Also try pulling down the status/notification bar (aka "window shade) and tapping on "Connect USB storage", that works for me

Comment: Also I have tried that. Only can click it. No changes. Also restart not helping.

Comment: Has it always been like this? Tried factory resetting ur device? :)

Comment: After I first connected it with PC and setup link for file transfer. I would like to wait a litle with factory reset. Also I'm afraid that this would happened again.

Comment: What OS are you on? Tried connecting it to a mac or linux based device if you are on windows? Do you have Kies installed?

Comment: I found the problem. It was in AC charger. I had to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the MTB connection only says that if I don't have adequate amperage for my tablet. You cannot just use any USB port to charge it, that's why it won't charge.

If you look at the specs on the original charger that came with it, it's a 5v (which is all USB ports) but it's 5v at 2A which is fairly high, and most cell chargers have anywhere from a 400ma (.4a) to a 800ma or .8a, and that is not enough amperage to run the unit and charge at the same time.

The USB ports on most computers also do not provide more than about 1Amp, so that will not work either.  It just kinda prolongs the life of the battery a bit.

However, if you turn the tablet off and charge it with a lesser amperage charger (one made for a cell phone or ipod) it will charge, but very slow.  The factory 2amp charger is a great amperage for the unit, and you can get knock off ones from ebay for less than 10 bucks shipped.

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

you try to access the service manual of the tab and try to see under one of those settings / options if you have an option that says USB CHARGE on/off. try this code to enter the serive manual of the phone *#*#197328640#*#*. it is under one of the options can be found there

Comment: this answer is very unclear. perhaps if you expanded on it a little?

Answer (score 0):

You may see the battery icon. If it changed from when the USB is not connected, then it is charging while doing USB MTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

My Samsung Galaxy 10.1 was charging normally until I plugged it into my PC. After that, plugging it into the charger straight into a wall socket produced a red cross in the battery icon, and a "MTP initialisation" notification, finishing with the USB icon in the bottom right row of icons.

Tried plugging and unplugging, and switching "USB Debugging" on/off, all with no effect.

Then blew into all of the sockets and tried again - tablet started charging normally. Problem fixed.

I must have a dusty PC.

Answer (score -2):

if MTP connection is still active when charging with your adapter, turn off the tablet and turn it on again. Solve the case most of the time.